# Selecting a model with a datetimestamp in the range of a day-of-week/time-of-day

Tags: django, django-models, calendar

I have a start day of the week and an end day of the week as choices in a configuration model

```
class config(models.Model)
...
    DAYS_OF_WEEK = (
    (0, 'Monday'),
    (1, 'Tuesday'),
    (2, 'Wednesday'),
    (3, 'Thursday'),
    (4, 'Friday'),
    (5, 'Saturday'),
    (6, 'Sunday'),
    )
    startday = models.Charfield(max_length = 1, choices=DAY_OF_WEEK)
    startday = models.Charfield(max_length = 1, choices=DAY_OF_WEEK)
    starttime = models.TimeField()
    endtime = models.Timefield()
```

I have separate model that has a datetimefield that holds a timestamped event.

```
class event(models.Model)
...
event_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

How can I grab all the config models that the event model falls within the start-end day/time ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this

```
day =  timestamp.weekday()
config = ZoneConfiguration.objects.get(video_channel = event.videochannel , zone_endday__gte = day, zone_startday__lte = day)
```

and redefined the start and end days as integers.

```
DAYS_OF_WEEK = (
            (0,'Monday'),
            (1,'Tuesday'),
            (2,'Wednesday'),
            (3,'Thursday'),
            (4,'Friday'),
            (5,'Saturday'),
            (6,'Sunday')
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Django docs state, you can filter datetime fields by week day.
That is, you can do

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__week_day=2) # Day 2 is Monday
```

Maybe you can also add the *range* filter/operator as follows

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__week_day__range=(2,4)) # Monday to wednesday
```

This is for the date part at least.